# Typescript Error when binding can to ability instance

Tags: typescript, casl

Simply pasting example code from [docs](https://casl.js.org/v5/en/package/casl-react#bind-can-to-a-particular-ability-instance)

```
import { createCanBoundTo } from '@casl/react';

import ability from './abilities';

export const Can = createCanBoundTo(ability);
```

Gives error on last line:

> Exported variable 'Can' has or is using name 'BoundCanClass' from
> external module
> "C:/Users/ahmefa04/Documents/SourceCode/temp-cd-next/node_modules/@casl/react/dist/types/factory"
> but cannot be named.ts(4023)

Edit: I exported BoundCanClass in the factory.d.ts file however when I try to use can in my application:

```
<Can I="view" on="all">
        <Button size="small" onClick={handleUpdateRow}>
          Update a user
        </Button>
</Can>
```

I get error:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props:
> BoundCanProps<Ability<AbilityTuple<string, Subject>, { published:
> boolean; }>>, context?: any): Can<Ability<AbilityTuple<string,
> Subject>, { ...; }>, true>', gave the following error.
> Type '{ children: Element[]; I: string; on: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> (IntrinsicClassAttributes<Can<Ability<AbilityTuple<string, Subject>, {
> published: boolean; }>, true>> & (Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>))'.
> Property 'this' is missing in type '{ children: Element[]; I: string; on: string; }' but required in type 'Readonly<{ I: string;
> this: AnyRecord; field?: string | undefined; } &
> BoundCanExtraProps<Ability<AbilityTuple<string, Subject>, { published:
> boolean; }>>>'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props:
> BoundCanProps<Ability<AbilityTuple<string, Subject>, { published:
> boolean; }>>, context?: any):
> Component<BoundCanProps<Ability<AbilityTuple<string, Subject>, { ...;
> }>>, any, any>', gave the following error.
> Type '{ children: Element[]; I: string; on: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> (IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<BoundCanProps<Ability<AbilityTuple<string,
> Subject>, { published: boolean; }>>, any, any>> & (Readonly<...> &
> Readonly<...>))'.
> Property 'this' is missing in type '{ children: Element[]; I: string; on: string; }' but required in type 'Readonly<{ I: string;
> this: AnyRecord; field?: string | undefined; } &
> BoundCanExtraProps<Ability<AbilityTuple<string, Subject>, { published:
> boolean; }>>>'.ts(2769)

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because `I` should be used with `a`, `an` or `this` props, to use `on` you should use `do` instead:

```
<Can I="view" a="all">
   <Button size="small" onClick={handleUpdateRow}>
      Update a user
    </Button>
</Can>
```

or

```
<Can do="view" on="all">
   <Button size="small" onClick={handleUpdateRow}>
      Update a user
    </Button>
</Can>
```

[Docs reference](https://casl.js.org/v5/en/package/casl-react#property-names-and-aliases)